# Cross join returning too few rows

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.6, cross-join

I have two tables below:

Table A

```
+--------+--------+--------+
| color  | shape  |  size  |
+--------+--------+--------+
| Red    | Square | Small  |
| Blue   | Square | Small  |
| Yellow | Square | Small  |
| Red    | Circle | Small  |
| Blue   | Circle | Small  |
| Yellow | Circle | Small  |
| Yellow | Square | Medium |
| Red    | Circle | Medium |
| Blue   | Circle | Medium |
| Yellow | Circle | Medium |
| Red    | Square | Large  |
| Red    | Circle | Large  |
| Blue   | Circle | Large  |
| Yellow | Circle | Large  |
+--------+--------+--------+
```

Table B

```
+---------------+
|     edge      |
+---------------+
| Straight Line |
| Dotted Line   |
| Squiggly Line |
+---------------+
```

I am running the following query:

```
WITH TableA (color, shape, size)
AS (SELECT DISTINCT color, shape, size
     FROM   TableA),

TableB (edge)
AS (SELECT DISTINCT edge
    FROM   TableB)

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 
(SELECT  a.*,
         b.*
FROM     TableA AS a
         CROSS JOIN TableB AS b) as x;
```

What I expect to happen: it will select all the distinct values from each column in Table A (color, shape, size), then select each unique value from each column in Table B (edge), then do a cross join producing every combination of color, shape, size, and edge.

I've checked that the part where the query selects unique values is working independently, but running it all together produces fewer rows than I am expecting.

With 3 colors, 2 shapes, 3 sizes, and 3 edges, I should get 54 possible combinations/rows, but am only getting 42.

Comment: What you expect to happen is not what actually occurs. In a CROSS JOIN each *row* from the first table is joined to all the *rows* in the other table. The join is done on a row-by-row basis, not on a field-by-field basis.

Comment: @BobJarvis I see now that that's what was happening, since 14 x 3 = 42. My query was selecting distinct combinations of color, shape, and size (which is all rows in Table A, since they're all unique), and cross joining with the rows in Table B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select the columns independently:

```
select c.olor, s.shape, sz.size, e.edge
from (select distinct color from a) c cross join
     (select distinct shape from a) s cross join
     (select distinct size from a) sz cross join
     (select distinct edge from b) e
```